# Transmit image file thougth the TX TR serial line

Tags: usbasp, camera

I have a digital camera with a USB port for image dowload from the camera SD card.

I will like to be able to capture this image files store in the camera SD card using the Arduino  TX TR lines (serial) then transmit this image file to the computer from the USB connection from Arduino to Computer.

The reason need this scenario responds to that the camera dissables the shutter when sensing a USB cable conneted to computer. I do not knwo why this happens but I suspect is an underdeveloped feature of the camera.

Basically, I will like to use Arduino as a USB hub for external devices but at the same time to power down the line when no longer need the device using the Arduino TX and TX line . This will give tha camera a sense that the camera is been unplugged.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcivGW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. The TX and RX lines are UART. UART is *not* USB. USB is a very complicated protocol, and you need a proper understanding of how it works. It's not a simple serial protocol like UART.

Add to that the fact that the Arduino can in no way handle the amount of data involved in video, and you're already on a non-starter.

Comment: Having this said, can you suggest a way to use Arduino to cut off the V data line transmition from the computer to the camera?  I need to fake the same as unplugging the USB.

Comment: What is the "V" transmission line? USB has D+ and D-, and they are both required all the time for communication.

Comment: @JoseEnriqueCalderon The closest you could possibly get would be to have the Arduino control a relay which disconnects both the D+ and D- lines from your computer, performing the same task as physically unplugging the camera. That means *no* communication in *either* direction.

Comment: If you want to read data from USB so connect an Arduino to an USB port, you must use an Arduino Leonardo. Arduinos don't have a "full USB", except the Leonardo.

Comment: @peter  , Please, I will like you to post this as an answear and in any way  elaborate a simple sketch or diagram. Thanks

Comment: @Majenko.... Thanks for the correction, I have found some places that uses this for voltage line and overlook that this is a data line.

Comment: The Leonardo's USB is device mode only. It can talk to a PC. It has no relevence to communicating with another USB device.